# Qt c++ how to use nested libraries

Tags: c++, qt

Hi im rather new to qt here. Im using QT subdir to better organize and modulate my code. 
I created a shared c++ library subproject (A) which uses the static gdal library. Then i created another shared c++ library subproject (B) which attempts to use (A).
Building (A) is okay. However the #includes for gdal dont work when i build (B). It says cannot open include file: 'ogr_feature.h': No such file or directory. 
I went to read the qt guide in creating shared libraries and it said when deploying the library there should be no dependency to internal headers. What does that mean and how do i work around it?

Comment: have you configured subproject B in .pro file to include the gdal header files? `INCLUDEPATH += <path to gdal includes>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Sorry the question wasnt so detailed. A is supposed to use gdal to get some values. B is supposed to grab the values from A and do some logic with them. Would it be okay to include the gdal includes in B?

Comment: post your qt `.pro` files

Comment: If in A you have some header files that includes gdal, and B includes those A's header files, B must have gdal in the include path, even if B doesn't use gdal direclty. Or you have to remove gdal from A headers, if you can (using forward declaration and put the gdal includes in the cpp files)

Comment: Sorry i hav t get home before i can post the .pro files. My office computer isnt connected to the net. Im on my mobile now. @Fabio thanks for the answer. However, lets say i decide to not use gdal and decide to use hdal, i would have to change the include path in  A and B? If more libs use A i would have a hard time changing them ><

Comment: Yes. The best solution is to hide the dependencies from A header files, moving the gdal include statements in cpp or h files that aren't visible from B

Comment: Okay i will try it out and update you! Thank you!

Comment: Hiding the includes in the cpp works! However it feels a little restrictive!